# Removing the default c# console application template code in visual studio 2022

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

When creating a console application project for .net 6.0 c# in visual studio, it generates the following code:

```
// See https://aka.ms/new-console-template for more information
Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
```

As opposed to previous c# versions, where the project template created some useful boilerplate, non of this is helpful whatsoever.

Is it possible to configure visual studio 2022 so that when creating console applications for c# in .net 6.0 the file will be completely empty?

Comment: [How to: Create project templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-create-project-templates?view=vs-2022)

Comment: Cast your vote here, a lot of people dislike the change. Alas at the moment there is no way but to create a .NET 5.0 application and changing it to 6.0 after creation. https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/27420

Comment: @CShark Personally I don't really have an issue with the lack of a top statement, my issue is more that if we aren't going to be using a top statement why are we adding 2 completely useless lines?

Comment: Although there should definitely be the option to create a project with the top statement alongside with the blank template.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, when creating a new solution, one has to select the "Do not use top-level statements" checkbox when selecting the .Net version, on the last step of the solution creation. Not exactly by default, but at least there is that option.

Answer (score 0):

From the official docs: create .NET 5 project and then change framework to .NET 6 via editing project file

https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/dotnet/core/tutorials/top-level-templates#use-the-old-program-style

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
-   <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
+   <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

---

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
+   <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
+   <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```